# How come zipping a created disk image, makes smaller files than piping?

Tags: pipe, zip, gzip

Case 1. I use `dd` to create an image:

```
dd if=/dev/rdiskx of=/path/to/image bs=1m.
```

It's 16 GB in size. I zip it, and it's suddenly around 100 MB.

Case 2. I use `dd` to create an image, piping it through gzip:

```
 dd bs=1m if=/dev/rdiskx | gzip > image.gz.
```

It's 11 GB in size.

How come, and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: That's a huge difference! I would be curious to know how `bzip2` compares to the other 2.

Comment: Pretty interesting.  Presuming gzip doesn't read the whole thing into memory first when piped, it does make sense that compression will be much better when you can consider everything than when you have to work with a stream of indeterminate size.  I can't find any explicit accounting for this WRT gzip online though, and I'm not tackling the source.

Comment: did you try using `pv` or `cat` instead of `dd`? i.e. `pv /dev/rdiskx | gzip > image.gz`

Comment: can you add the missing bits of case1: you don't have the zip part.

Comment: Also, as well as richard's comment, can you add the output of `ls -l image.gz` in both cases (assuming that's what you called it).  Lastly, are you sure rdiskx isn't changing between executions?

Comment: Hmmm, in fact I just tried this with 1 GB of identical data (`bs=1M`) and it comes out the same both ways.  So either you've made a mistake here, or gzip does something different depending on the potential for it to read the input stream entirely into memory; i.e., at a certain point it stops and compresses what it has, then continues, and this point depends on available RAM.  How much memory was free on the system when you used the pipe?

Comment: Which command are you using to "zip" the image file?

Comment: Does `dd bs=1m if=/path/to/image | gzip > image.gz` show the same discrepancy?

Comment: @goldilocks Actually, I am almost out of disk space. Would that explain it? Also, I'm on a Mac, so it's the terminal of Mac I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it has to do with gzip's [DEFLATE](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-deflate.html) algorithm and the small dictionary size (32K) it uses.

Try experimenting with different `bs` values as well. Try 32K for example.

Also wondering if the first dd is somehow storing that image as a sparse file.

Does the image preserve it's size before / after compression / decompression? Is there a difference in values from `du -sm` and `ls -la`?

Comment: +1 I agree it must have something to do with one of the two compression methods dealing much better with that specific data. Nothing to do with "piping" per se. However, note than sparse file or not can't really have anything to do with it.